# How to pass a generic to a function inside callEffect

Tags: typescript, generics, redux-saga

I have a function that performs api calls and receives a generic that ultimately would be the returned data type:

```js
export const apiCall = async <T>(route: string, method: 'get' | 'post', body: {}): Promise<AxiosResponse<T> | AxiosError<T>> => {
  try {
    return await axios[method](route, body)
  } catch (err) {
    return err as AxiosError<T>
  }
}
```

then I have the following saga:

```js
function* signIn (...some args) {
  try {   
    const res = yield* call(apiCall, `/signin`, 'post', { ...body request data });      
    yield* put(signInSuccess(res.data));
  } catch (err) {
    yield* put(signInFailure(err as AxiosError<AxiosResponse<SignInFailureError>>));
  }
}
```

this works but I would like to type the return of apiCall function, as you can see my apiCall function requires a generic to define the returned type I get from the axios request whether it is data or an error response.

I tried this (UserInfo is the return type I expect):

```js
const res = yield* call(apiCall<UserInfo>, `/signin`, 'post', { ...body request data });
```

but it gives me an error:

```
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '{context: unknown; fn: (this: unknown, ...args: any[]) => any; }'
```

so, how one type a function inside call effect?

PD: just in case, I'm using `yield*` instead of `yield` because I'm using the `typed-redux-saga` library.